# Pushing a development career forward after reaching technical competency

Tags: software-industry

I've been involved in intensive practical programming for about 6 years now, including about 4 years in the working world, and lots of studying and reading on my own time, including most of the major 'coding bibles'.

No doubt I still have some technical blank spots, but for the most part I'm a confident enough programmer, and my experience is extensive enough, that I don't feel the need to constantly learn on my own time, outside of keeping my eye on emerging trends.

All that said, I'm reasonably sure that my personality is oriented to technical roles. I'm way too introverted to manage, so being a worker it is. In that regard, though, it feels like I've reached a plateau where I'm competent enough to fill my role, but don't have much avenue to improve my job security or develop my career.

Switching roles isn't an option as I've also plateaued in terms of compensation in the city I'm in, and have some pretty favourable benefits. **So am I just stuck in the classic place that introverted devs end up, or is there anything useful I can do?**

Comment: You must be a much quicker learner than I am. I've been learning about computers for 50 years, including over 30 years in the working world, and there is still so much that I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move up as a senior engineer, or architect, or another role where a person needs to make important *technical* decisions.

Things like designing a correct system topology, evaluating whether an approach is feasible etc. requires a skilled and experienced person. Giving an opinion which can be *trusted* (v.s. the junior programming saying "I will give it a try" or "I heard this might work") can be a very valuable. You are in a good position to provide this feedback as you have solid experiences working hands-on programming tasks.

These decisions can be very technically challenging, and certainly different than managing a team and setting everyone's schedule.

Comment: Some companies have parallel promotion tracks, allowing senior engineers and architects to earn the same as managers. The OP should try to get into that sort of environment.

Answer (score 3):

> So am I just stuck in the classic place that introverted devs end up, or is there anything useful I can do?

**You're as stuck as you think you are.**

The lead-up to your question reads to me like a list of excuses for standing still:

- No need to learn new things because...*you can learn anything when you need it?*
- Stuck being a follower because...*introverts can't learn to lead?*
- Can't change roles because...*you have sweet benefits?*
- Your career options are limited because...*you've mastered the practice of computer programming after four whole years of actual work experience?*

Sure, I've twisted your words a little bit, but only to make it plain that the things that you think are limiting your growth are mostly in your head. Each wall of the box you think you're in can be knocked down easily:

- Programming is so much more than becoming proficient in a list of tools. It's *building things* and *solving problems*, and there are so many approaches and techniques to those activities that you couldn't master all of them in a lifetime.
- Being an introvert doesn't mean that you're forever limited how you interact with other people any more than being an extrovert makes you a natural born leader. Learning management skills doesn't mean having to perform in front of a crowd.
- If you work for a company that provides *any* benefits, you probably work for a company that has a variety of roles to fill and that might be interested in helping employees expand their skills. It's very likely that the role you have could shift or expand to help you get some new and different experience, all without affecting your compensation package.
- There are all kinds of career options for someone who can solve problems with code, and there are all kinds of things you could learn in your current position that would change the way you think about programming and take your skills up a notch.

I don't want to assume too much, but it sounds to me like you're in a bit of a rut and have gotten *bored* with your job. If so, it's totally understandable -- I think most people feel that way from time to time. And being "stuck" is really only a problem until you recognize it and decide to do something about it. So congratulations -- you may already be on your way to better things.

I'm not sure anyone here can tell you exactly how to get unstuck and un-bored because each person is different, but there are some general themes that apply:

- **shake things up:** Make some changes in your life and your job just for the sake of doing things differently and getting a fresh perspective. Maybe go to sleep and get up earlier (or later) than usual. Trade tasks with some of the other developers on your team. Spend a day or two shadowing someone in a completely different department so that you see a different side of the business. Go to lunch with a coworker that you never talk to.
- **try something new:** Push yourself to bust out of your comfort zone, and not just at work. If you think of yourself as an object-oriented programmer, try some functional programming. If you've never been much of an athlete or a dancer or an artist, sign up for a sport or a dance or art class. Even if you don't end up sticking with it, trying something new makes you see yourself in a new way, and it can give you confidence to imagine the next phase of your career.
- **seek outside advice:** It's hard to be objective about your own strengths and weaknesses, so it can be hard to know what aspects of your self you should try to improve. Advice from a team lead, manager, or mentor can be invaluable in establishing goals for getting better at what you do. Talking to your manager or lead about how to improve is also a good way to let them know that you're eager to advance; if they're good at what they do, they'll look for opportunities to help you do that.
- **don't give up:** Not everything you try will help you improve, but don't let that stop you. Keep at it and you'll be bound to make progress. It may help to keep a log or journal of the what you're trying to accomplish.

So, one last time: you don't need to be stalled in your current position if you don't want to be; you're just in a comfortable local minimum, and moving beyond it will require some effort and persistence.

Answer (score 2):

Keep learning - I've been at this for 10 years full-time and there is always something new - new tools, updates to languages (PHP and C++ have both changed rather dramatically over the years), new patterns and approaches.  I'm constantly reviewing my knowledge of software design and user experience design.

Diversify - I started on PHP; got to grips with XSL, Javascript, HTML, CSS; database design (still loads to learn there); picked up a little Python and Perl; and now mostly do C++. Everything thing I've learnt for all of those things has helped add to my overall knowledge for software design.

Know there is always something new - not once have I felt I only had a "few small holes" - there's just too much knowledge out there to learn.

Go for the bigger picture - start getting into systems design.

Go deeper and master the knowledge you already have - each time I think I've mastered something in software and application design, I discover a whole new layer beneath to get stuck into.

Comment: I do agree, although feel like I've gotten to the point where if I really *need* to know something I can just pick it up in a few weeks, so learning stuff that's not relevant right now has pretty low returns.

Comment: @mcraen Who's to say what is and isn't relevant? There's stuff I've learnt in Python and Perl and C++ that have help improved my skills in PHP - there's stuff I've learnt from various frameworks (including ones I've never actually used for any actual project) that have helped me learn better approaches to design (and also what not to do). If you really have reached the point you think you have after only a few years, I envy you - seems I always find five new things to learn after each thing I've mastered.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a niche that hasn't been covered however obscure and develop something original. There is still plenty out there. You don't need to invent Windows to make money.

Once you have a product then look at marketing it, but meanwhile just develop a product.

I talk to a lot of experienced professionals in many fields, I'm interested in their industries because sometimes I can spot something that is needed, more efficient and potentially lucrative they just don't know it yet because no one has looked at it with my knowledge of different ways problems can be solved.